# sql server send output messages by email

Tags: sql-server

I have been running up a stored procedure that runs several separate update and insert statements. It also prints some status messages that I can see in sql management studio. I am going to automate this procedure to run overnight but need the output as a final check to be sent to me.

I know how to use the email stored procedure and have that working but can't find where the message output i.e. (10 rows affected)... is all stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informational messages like '10 rows affected' or PRINT output are sent straight to the client and you can't capture it in Transact-SQL. You can, however, *be* the client if you are a CLR procedure, and in that case you will get all the output from the procedure you invoked. Requires SQL Server 2005 or newer for CLR.

A much better alternative is to have the procedure create a true output, like a rowset result or output parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you can always store the output in a table

```
 exec master..xp_sendmail       
 @recipients  = 'you@you.com',      
 @subject  = 'my alert'.     
 @query   = 'select * from mytable'
```

Comment: You will have to set up SQL Mail on the server for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get information messages from t-sql.

Answer (score 0):

PRINT @WIDELOAD